# How to get uv_on_emitter for child particles?

Tags: particles

I wonder if there is possibility to get uv_on_emitter for all particles including child particles?
My loop over particles look like this:

```
for pindex in range(0, num_parents + num_children): 
    p_uv = partSystem.uv_on_emitter(mod, partSystem.particles[pindex])
```

When there are children enabled I got index out of range because partSystem.particles returns only parents, not the children.

Comment: children are in `particle_systems['ParticleSystem'].child_particles.items()[x][1]` which is a [ChildParticle](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_75_3/bpy.types.ChildParticle.html) not sure where their location is.

Comment: The problem is that ChildParticle won't help me much as uv_on_emitter is expecting Particle type.

Answer (score 1):

Heres what you do:

```
if pindex >= num_parents:
   particle = psys.particles[(pindex - num_parents) % num_parents]
else:
   particle = psys.particles[pindex]
st = psys.uv_on_emitter(psys_modifier, particle, pindex)
```

Comment: interesting, but could you please elaborate by editing your answer what and why you do here?